# Loop through subfolders in a parent folder in Makefile

Tags: linux, docker, for-loop, makefile, find

I have a folder containing unknown number of subfolders. Each subfolder contains a `Dockerfile`. I want to write a `Makefile` command to batch build all images named after the subfolder and tag them accordingly.

I started with simple trial first:

```
build.all.images:
    for f in $(find $(image_folder) -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec basename {} \;); do echo $${f}; done
```

When I run the `find` command separately with value for `image_folder` hard-coded, subfolders are listed successfully. However, when I tried to run the make command, I only see the output below:

```
for f in ; do echo ${f}; done
```

I have also tried to use `ls` command chained with `tf` `cut` to get the list of sub-folders but the result was the same.

```
build.all.images:
    for f in $(ls -l $(image_folder) | grep '^d' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9); do echo $${f}; done
```

What am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recipes are expanded by make before they are executed by the shell. So `$(find something)` is expanded and, as there is no make macro named `find something`, it is replaced by the empty string. Double the `$` sign (or use backticks) just like you did for shell variable `f`:

```
build.all.images:
    for f in $$(find $(image_folder) -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec basename {} \;); do echo $${f}; done
```

But using a `for` loop in a make recipe is frequently a not that good idea. Makefiles are not shell scripts. With your solution (after fixing the `$` issue) you will not benefit from the power of make. Make analyzes dependencies between targets and prerequisites to redo only what needs to. And it also has parallel capabilities that can be very useful to speed-up your building process.

Here is another more make-ish solution. I changed a bit the logic to find Dockerfiles instead of sub-directories but it is easy to adapt if you prefer the other way.

```
DOCKERFILES := $(shell find $(image_folder) -type f -name Dockerfile)
TARGETS     := $(patsubst %/Dockerfile,%.done,$(DOCKERFILES))

.PHONY: build.all.images clean

build.all.images: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): %.done: %/Dockerfile
    printf 'sub-directory: %s, Dockerfile: %s\n' "$*" "$<"
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS)
```

Demo:

```bash
$ mkdir -p {a..d}
$ touch {a..d}/Dockerfile
$ make -s -j4 build.all.images
sub-directory: c, Dockerfile: c/Dockerfile
sub-directory: a, Dockerfile: a/Dockerfile
sub-directory: d, Dockerfile: d/Dockerfile
sub-directory: b, Dockerfile: b/Dockerfile
```

With this approach you will rebuild an image only if its Dockerfile changed since the last build. The date/time of the last build of image `FOO` is the last modification date/time of the empty file named `FOO.done` that the recipe creates or touches after the build. So, that is less work to do.

Moreover, as the static pattern rule is equivalent to as many independent rules as you have images to build, make can build the outdated images in parallel. Try `make -j 8 build.all.images` if you have 8 cores and see.

Comment: Wow, Renaud! You completely blowed it! You not only answered my question but went miles ahead to solve my whole problem in a way better than I thought. Thank you so much!

Comment: Warning: there were typos in my previous Makefile. I fixed them, please use the new version.

Comment: I actually run into an issue `Makefile:61: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.`  on line `printf 'sub-directory: %s, Dockerfile: %s\n' "$*" "$<"`

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, please use the current version instead.

Comment: And do not just copy-paste, in recipe lines replace leading spaces by tabs.